# Why am I getting an error in my SQL command?

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-error-1064

mysql>

```
CREATE TABLE twitter(
     username varchar(255), 
     created_at varchar(45),tweet text, 
     retweet_count int(11), 
    location varchar(100), 
     place varchar(100), 
  PRIMARY KEY int(11));
```

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'int(11))' at line 1mys

Comment: `PRIMARY KEY int(11)` what is your intent?

Answer (score 2):

The `PRIMARY KEY` clause is wrong.

You need to specify a name for your primary key column.

So, that would be ... `id int(11), PRIMARY KEY (id));`

Comment: mysql> CREATE TABLE twitter(id int(11), username varchar(255), created_at varchar(45),tweet text, retweet_count int(11), location varchar(100), place varchar(100), PRIMARY KEY id);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

Comment: Computers tend to be awfully picky about being told what to do in a very precise way, down to the tiniest little opening or closing parenthesis. You did not type precisely what I suggested that you should type.  Try again.

Answer (score 0):

You can not define `PRIMARY KEY` like that. The syntax for `PRIMARY KEY` is

```
PRIMARY KEY(Id)
```

Where you'll also have to create a column named Id

```
Id int(11)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
CREATE TABLE twitter (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username varchar(255), 
    created_at varchar(45),
    tweet text, 
    retweet_count int(11), 
    location varchar(100), 
    place varchar(100), 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```